# Getting an argument from a private constructor

Tags: scala

I want to get access to an argument in a private constructor without using mutable variables:

```
class Class1 {

  val strArgPublic = // get strArg argument from the private constructor. How?

  private def this(strArg: String) = {
    //.....
  }
}
```

I want not only get `strArg` and return it, but change it a little bit and return a new modified copy of it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Modify it in private constructor and then pass it to the main constructor.

Comment: The primary constructor should be the most general of all constructors.  If you want to keep the body of the class as clean as possible you can use a companion object with factory methods in place of constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not only private constructor in your class. There is also a public constructor. You should decide what will be a value of `strArgPublic` after public constructor. If there is should be no public constructor you should define your class like this:

```
class Class1 private(strArg: String) {
  val strArgPublic = transform(strArg)
}
```

If there should be a parameterless public constructor you could define one as auxiliary constructor:

```
class Class1 private(strArg: String) {
  val strArgPublic = transform(strArg)
  def this() = this("default")
}
```

Comment: what does say there is also a public constructor there? Does just saying `class Class1 { ... }` imply that?

Comment: there should not a public constructor.

Comment: @MariusKavansky: there is always a primary constructor in every scala class.

Comment: if the constructor is private, how will it be possible to pass arguments to it (strArg)?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: from auxiliary constructor (see my answer), from companion object, from other instance.